# Why datagridview autocomplete textbox backcolor become black?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Below is the code I am using to make my DGV textbox cell as autocomplete textbox.

```
private void dgvEntryVerify_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txtBox = e.Control as TextBox;
            txtBox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Normal;

            DataGridViewCell currentCell = dgvEntryVerify.CurrentCell;
            List<string> tmpList = new List<string>();
            string tmpValue = "";

            try
            {

                if (e.Control is TextBox)
                {
                    tmpValue = "";
                    tmpList.Clear();

                    TextBox currentTextBox = e.Control as TextBox;
                    currentTextBox.Multiline = false;

                    currentTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                    currentTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                    currentTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

                    if (currentCell.OwningColumn.Name.Contains("Parish"))
                    {
                        tmpValue = "";
                        tmpList.Clear();
                        tmpValue = currentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
                        tmpList = GlobalSettings.LookupParish.FindAll(t => t.StartsWith(tmpValue));
                        if (tmpList.Count > 0)
                        {
                            currentTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(tmpList.ToArray());
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
```

But in the UI, auto complete textbox become black which I need to be white so that I can see the same value that I have selected from the list.
 [image]
Any solution to this is highly appreciated.

I am using VS2012, C# Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

The black cell is caused by one specific line of code in your routine:

```
tmpValue = currentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
```

I have not looked further as to why that occurs, but since you are not using `tmpValue` at all, commenting the line out will resolve your issue.